# Can't find out a correct fuel pump for my vehicle

Tags: dodge, fuel-pump, charger

I have a 2008 Dodge Charger SRT8 6.1l.

The trick is, that I need a fuel pump replacement for that vehicle and I can't find the appropriate part.
Fuel tank capacity is 72 liters (22 gallons)... On the market, there are only 18 gal and 19 gal versions and most of the time it's for 5.7l engine and not indicated for 6.1l which I found strange.

Could someone explain me how to properly find a correct fuel pump, please?

Going to a dealer here in Europe cost me a little more than $600 (US) compared to prices on the web (from $100 to $300).

**==== UPDATED ====**

I have purchased a fuel pump before, which also died (had dirt inside the tank). That fuel pump was actually for 5.7L (18 gallons), and whenever my fuel drops lower than 1/4 tank, the fuel level on the dashboard stops moving. So, I ran out of gas couple times before I figured it out... (it's just information for 18 and 19 gal versions)

Comment: Wow, a SRT8 Charger must be pretty unique in Europe, and I'm not surprised the parts are expensive.

Comment: 72 L / 3.76 L/g = 19.15g

Comment: @rpmerf: An imperial (UK) gallon is 4.54609 Litres. 72 Litres = 16 UK Gallons, 19 US Gallons. The OP is in the UK. Paulster2's answer, of search by model number, is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears there are two pumps which it could actually be. One each for the left and right sides of the vehicle. The part numbers I can find are:

Right side:

- Spectra Premium - SP7050M
- Bosch - 67774

Left side:

- Mopar - RL161808AE
- Spectra Premium - SP7051M

These are for the SRT8 6.1L Hemi. These models are for exact fit with housing. You can get a cheaper generic pump which you'd have to fit into the current housing.

Comment: Paul, thank you so much for your info! Could you please tell me how did you found out which part I need exactly ? Visually, it's almost the same as Origin, except the fuel meter lever in OE does not have a Sphere shape. I will update the question

Comment: I went to [RockAuto.com](http://www.rockauto.com). They usually have the best information about parts. If you cannot find these exact parts, you can use the numbers to cross-reference and find something which will be good for your vehicle. I didn't realize the Challengers/Chargers have dual tanks (or pumps) ... that's interesting.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Not only two pumps... two different pumps it seems. Perhaps just mirrored w.r.t. outputs, or something.

Comment: @Nick - I believe the pumps themselves are exactly the same. The difference is the holder (brackets, whatever) which keeps them in place. RockAuto offers a stand alone pump which I believe will fit in either holder, but you have to install it at that level, not just a drop in like the other models are.

Comment: Actually I don't know if there is any difference between spherical or rectangle shape of the fuel lever on that fuel pump assembly.